# error TypeError: Failed to fetch - express js

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, postman, web-development-server

I have tested the api is working fine in postman but when i try to run on localhost it shows this error: TypeError: Failed to fetch .

I have tried using `corsOptions` and  Access-Control-Allow-Origin but both didn't solved my error.

When I try to run on localhost, it shows output in terminal:

result= { NAME: 'myname',
EMAIL: 'anymail@gmail.com',
IS_VERIFIED: 1,
PSWD: 'password' }
true
true
success
Please help me out, I have spent more than 50hrs but didn't found any solution.Thanks

Server-side code(node):

```
app.post('/checkLogin', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res) {
    var result = {};
    
    let Inputdata = { email: req.body.email, pass: req.body.password };
    console.log("Input data=", Inputdata);
    let selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM "schema"."tablename"  WHERE "EMAIL"='${Inputdata.email}';`
    
    ibmdb.open(connStr, function (err, conn) {

        //blocks until the query is completed and all data has been acquired
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("error in db connection:",err);
        }
        
        var rows = conn.querySync(selectQuery);
        result = rows[0];
        console.log("result=", result);
        if (result != undefined)
        {
            console.log(result.PSWD === Inputdata.pass)
        console.log(result.IS_VERIFIED == 1)
        if (result.PSWD == Inputdata.pass && result.IS_VERIFIED == 1) {
            console.log("success")
            res.status(200).send({ data: { token: 'this is a pretend token' } });
             }

        else {
            console.log("Failed")
            res.status(401).send({
                error: { code: 401, message: 'invalid username or password.' },
            });
            }
        
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(401).send({
                error: { code: 401, message: 'invalid username or password.' },
            });
            
            }
        
    });
});
```

client-side code(js):

```
function doLogin() { 
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  
  

  var raw = JSON.stringify({"email":document.getElementById('inputEmail').value,"password":document.getElementById('inputPassword').value});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:50000/checkLogin", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

my html form:

```html
    <form class="form-signin">
       <!-- Input email address-->
                  <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                    <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                  </div>
    
      <!-- Input password-->
                  <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                  </div>
    
      <!-- Input check box to remember password-->
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Remember password</label>
                  </div>
    
     <!-- Login button-->
                  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" onclick="doLogin()">Sign in</button>
                  <hr class="my-4">
    
    <!--signup libk -->
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <label >Not a member ? &nbsp;
                    <a href="signup.html" style="color: #f4623a">Sign up Now</a>
                    </label> 
                  </div>
                  
                </form>
```

Comment: WHat error in console did you have and in a response from a request?

Comment: Try using relative URLS?

Comment: Exactly this error in browser console:   error TypeError: Failed to fetch @Anatoly

Comment: Can you please elaborate @expressjs123 thanks

Comment: And what about a request? What response did you get there?

Comment: @Anatoly When I called api through postman I got this response for wrong password: {
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "invalid username or password."
    }
}

Comment: It worked as expected in postman but giving error when i run in browser

Comment: But in a browser you also can look at a request in dev tools.

Comment: No response there(in network tab of dev tools) @Anatoly